# Java: Socket receiving data partially

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to send data from the client to the server through sockets. The client successfully sends TD to the server but num_Decimal is not received and the socket stays there for listening. The code does not show any error messages but I have to force the computer to stop as it doesn't move ahead. I am pasting only the relevant code below.

Could someone please help me in this regard. Thanks.

Client Side:

```
Socket clisock=new Socket("172.27.69.11",9090);
ObjectOutputStream os=new ObjectOutputStream(clisock.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream is=new ObjectInputStream(clisock.getInputStream());
os.writeLong(TD);
os.flush();
os.writeLong(num_Decimal);
```

Server Side:

```
ServerSocket S4=new ServerSocket(9090);
Socket sss=S4.accept();
ObjectOutputStream osss=new ObjectOutputStream(clisock.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream isss=new ObjectInputStream(clisock.getInputStream());
keywordss=isss.readLong();
parts=isss.readLong();
S4.close();
osss.close();
isss.close();
```

Comment: Umm ... so why don't you put the flush after the 2nd writeLong?

Comment: Thanks. It works now.

Comment: Why are you using `Object(Input|Output)Stream` when you are not sending objects?  Use `Data(Input|Output)Stream` instead.